# Not able to dynamically truncate table in Redshift Stored Procedure

Tags: amazon-redshift

I have a table in Redshift (let's call it a status table) where I set the status of tables which I want to truncate. I created a Redshift [Stored Procedure](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/en_pv/redshift/latest/dg/stored-procedure-overview.html) in order to achieve that. Here is my code for the SP:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE <schema>.truncate_table()
AS $$
DECLARE
    v_tpsl RECORD;
    exec_statement VARCHAR(256);
BEGIN
    FOR v_tpsl in SELECT * from <schama>.tablename_process_status_log WHERE status = 'TRUE' LOOP
    exec_statement = 'TRUNCATE TABLE <schema>.' + quote_ident(v_tpsl.staging_table_name) + '_test;';
    RAISE INFO 'statement = %', exec_statement;
    EXECUTE exec_statement;
  END LOOP;
END;
$$
LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

Now when I am CALLING the Stored Procedure, I am getting this error:
`SQL Error [500310] [34000]: [Amazon](500310) Invalid operation: cursor does not exist;`

[image]

I looked at the documentation of the SP to check if Truncate is possible or not. By looking at the [examples](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/en_pv/redshift/latest/dg/c_PLpgSQL-statements.html#r_PLpgSQL-loops), it looks like it's possible.

I am not sure what is going wrong in this. I am using **RedshiftJDBC42-no-awssdk-1.2.34.1058.jar** and connecting via DBeaver.

Comment: Try using regular PostgreSQL instead of a buggy fork.

Comment: @LaurenzAlbe - That's a good suggestion but that can't be done as we want to use it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like I have found the answer. According to [this](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/en_pv/redshift/latest/dg/stored-procedure-transaction-management.html), `Any cursor that is open (explicitly or implicitly) is closed automatically when a COMMIT, ROLLBACK, or TRUNCATE statement is processed`. In my next iteration of the loop, it's trying to accessing the cursor which is already closed.

Comment: This isn't much of an answer. You're just confirming what the problem was. What did you implement as a solution to this problem?